# Regular expression for file name convention matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My python script does the following:

1. take root directory input from the user.
2. scan all subdirectories for image files.
3. create a list of all **legal** file names.

where a legal file extention is:

```
"<DDMMYY>\<a 6 letter word>\<a 8 letter OR digit word>\<coutner>_Plot<3 digit number>_row<3 digit number>.jpg"
```

for example:

> "190419\yotamr\yotam123\0001_Plot003_row004.jpg"

I am working with a .json as a config file, thus I want to have an entry to hold the regEx value for the file extension format.

I have supplied the following regular expression:

```
FORMAT = r'([0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9])\\([a-zA-Z]{6})\\([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\\\\d{4}_Plot\\d{3}_row\\d{3}\\.[jpeg]'
```

Nevertheless, every time I run the attached code, I keep getting 'None' as output from `re.match()`

```
match = re.match(FORMAT, "190419\yotamr\yotam123\0001_Plot003_row004.jpg")
print(match)
```

Any ideas for changes that make it work?

Comment: Your `\\d{4}` matches ``\`` and then 4 `d`s. ``\\.[jpeg]`` matches a ``\`` and then any char, and then `j` or `p` or `e` or `g`

Comment: Because you are using a raw string (`r'...'`) the `\\ ` gets preserved as two back-slashes, not one.  The `\\\\d` matches **three** backslashes then a digit.  Try printing `FORMAT` and you'll see what I mean.  Doubling the backslashes defeats the object of using a raw string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

text = "190419\\yotamr\\yotam123\\0001_Plot003_row004.jpg"

format = r"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\[a-zA-Z]{6}\\[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\\[0-9]{4}_Plot[0-9]{3}_row[0-9]{3}.jpg"

result = re.search(format, text)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, Gokhan,
now I see the problem.

When I load the "format" key from the .json file, I get a string and not a regular expression.

have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your regexp. Here is the correct:

```
FORMAT2 = re.compile(r'([0-3][0-9][0-1]([0-9]{3}))\\([a-zA-Z]{6})\\([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\\([0-9]{4})_Plot([0-9]{3})_row([0-9]{3})\.jpe?g')
```

```
>>> print(re.search(FORMAT2, "190419\\yotamr\\yotam123\\0001_Plot003_row004.jpg"))

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 46), match='190419\\yotamr\\yotam123\\0001_Plot003_row004.jpg>
```

Also don't forget to use `r` predicate in regexp strings: `r'WAKA[0-9]WAKA'` and to escape string you are checking (with `r` predicate or manual escaping, for example), because your string:

```
"190419\yotamr\yotam123\0001_Plot003_row004.jpg"
                       ^
                 here--|
```

contains null byte `'\0'` that converts to `'\x00'`.